# Calling recreate() in an Activity causes "Fatal Signal 11"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using this code to recreate my activities whenever the user changes application language:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("language"))
            recreate();
    }
}
```

This code works as it's supposed to work in any activity which does not have fragments. However, if my activity contains one or more fragments, a `Fatal Signal 11 (SIGSEGV)` is thrown right after returning from `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` and before `onCreate()` is called a second time. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I'm currently compiling against SDK version 19 with ADT build v 22.6.2 - 1085508 on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: What is restartActivity? What are you testing on (genymotion by any chance)?

Comment: @VM4 restartActivity() was just a wrapper for recreate(). Updated code. I'm testing on Kitkat and JB4.3, both in simulator and on real device.

Comment: I assume you're unregistering your listener in onStop? Also on API > 11 you should implement your listener in a fragment NOT in an Activity.

Comment: @VM4 No I was not unregistered my listeners. And I have a listener in a fragment for another purpose. I'll modify my code and post the results

Comment: @VM4 Not having unregistered my listeners seems to be the problem. If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unregister your listener in onPause or in onStop:

```
@Override     
protected void onStop() {         
    super.onStop();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);    
}
```